# Spring Boot JPA deletion does not reflect on database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a rest api and stucking at cart item deletion. I can't delete cart item in placeOrder function although I have check everything carefully.

```
    
    @PostMapping("/placeOrder/{userID}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> placeOrder(@PathVariable int userID, @RequestBody OrderModel orderModel) {
        // Get list of cartItem
        Optional<User> user = userService.findById(userID);
        List<CartItem> cartItems = user.get().getCart().getCartItems();
        // Map and save order from request
        Order newOrder = modelMapper.map(orderModel, Order.class);
        newOrder.setOrderedDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        newOrder.setUser(user.get());
        newOrder = orderService.save(newOrder);
        // Create a list of order items
        List<OrderItem> orderItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Set for order item
        // Remove products with quantity
        long total = 0;
        for (CartItem cartItem: cartItems) {
            OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem();
            Product product = cartItem.getProduct();
            orderItem.setPrice(cartItem.getProduct().getPrice());
            orderItem.setOrder(newOrder);
            orderItem.setQuantity(cartItem.getQuantity());
            orderItem.setProduct(product);
            orderItem = orderItemService.save(orderItem);
            orderItemList.add(orderItem);
            total += product.getPrice() * cartItem.getQuantity();
            // Update quantity
            if (orderItem.getProduct().getQuantity() - orderItem.getQuantity() >= 0)
                product.setQuantity(orderItem.getProduct().getQuantity() - orderItem.getQuantity());
            // Set status,...
            product = productService.save(product);
            cartItemService.delete(cartItem);
        }
        cartItemService.deleteById(4);
        // Remove cart items
        Cart mycart = cartService.findByUser(user.get()).get();
        mycart.setCartItems(null);
        mycart = cartService.save(mycart);
        // Set status and total
        // Shipping fee //
        newOrder.setTotal(total);
        newOrder.setOrderItems(orderItemList);
        newOrder = orderService.save(newOrder);
        // Map
        OrderModel newOrderModel = modelMapper.map(newOrder, OrderModel.class);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newOrderModel, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

However, the deletion in the below code is working perfectly.

```
@ResponseBody
    @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateCart(@RequestBody CartItemModel cartItemModel) {
        // Find cartitem
        Optional<CartItem> cartItem = cartItemService.findById(cartItemModel.getCartItemID());
        // Find user
        Optional<User> user = userService.findById(cartItem.get().getCart().getUser().getUserID());
        // Update cartitem
        if (cartItemModel.getQuantity() == 0) {
            cartItemService.delete(cartItem.get());
        } else {
            cartItem.get().setQuantity(cartItemModel.getQuantity());
            CartItem thisCartItem = cartItemService.save(cartItem.get());
        }
        Cart myCart = user.get().getCart();
        // Map to reply
        CartModel myCartModel = modelMapper.map(myCart, CartModel.class);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(modelMapper.map(myCartModel, CartModel.class), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I've observed in the console and there is no delete query when the function placeOrder is called, in contrast with update function.
Please help me with this. I am going mad. Thank all of you very much.